# In Linqpad c# statement how to compare string with is greater than (Version > 4.0.38000)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linqpad

in my data bases i have data name Version and i want to check
or show the version that greater than 4.0.38000

how should do this ? 
example of my code

```
string key = "4.0.";

innerjoin.Where(x=> x.Version.Contains(key)).Dump();
```

Where version is the string, but my code is not the correct one

pls help thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you are asking, but I'm assuming you want to compare Version strings.

Use the [`VersionClass`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version(v=vs.110).aspx) to compare version strings

> Version numbers consist of two to four components: major, minor,
>   build, and revision. The major and minor components are required; the
>   build and revision components are optional, but the build component is
>   required if the revision component is defined. All defined components
>   must be integers greater than or equal to 0. The format of the version
>   number is as follows (optional components are shown in square brackets
>   ([ and ]):
>
> ```
> major.minor[.build[.revision]]
> ```

Comment: You can use the Version initializer or you can use Version.Parse but in both cases you can't use it with entity-framework (or probably the question is not related to entity framework).